# How can I fix this @typescript-eslint warning using an arrow function with "this" inside?

Tags: typescript, eslint, typescript-eslint

I'm using this typescript code:

```
const tryThis = () => {
  const methods = {
    Login() {
      console.log("I'm Login()")
    },

    OnInit() {
      this.Login()
    }
  }

  return methods
}
```

but `@typescript-eslint` warns me with:

1. `Unsafe member access .Login on an any value. eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access`
2. `Unsafe call of an any typed value. eslint@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-call`

Why?

How can I fix this?

Comment: You can explicitly supply the type of this in a method definition: `(this: { Login: () => void, OnInit: () => void })`, for example. I'm not sure why you get that warning, though; TS seems to be able to infer that type for `this` itself.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your eslint config, the linter might not allow access to members with `any` type. To fix that you can fix that in your .eslintrc.js file with `"no-unsafe-any": false` check [here](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/master/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/no-unsafe-member-access.md#disallows-member-access-on-any-typed-variables-no-unsafe-member-access), or type your function.

```
type ThisType = () => {
    Login(): void;
    OnInit(): void;
}

const tryThis:ThisType = () => {
  const methods = {
    Login() {
      console.log("I'm Login()")
    },

    OnInit() {
      this.Login()
    }
  }

  return methods
}
```